# Prevent page break after end of environment (e.g. verse)

Tags: environments, page-breaking, verse

Dear ladies and gentlemen,

I have been typesetting verse and prose recently, and I am having trouble with dates. Specifically, I want to have the date follow the preceding text immediately, and stick to it (e.g., no pagebreak). This seems to be obvious whenever prose is being typeset---see this workaround:

```
\newcommand{\dated}[1]{\nobreak\par\noindent\null\hfill\textit{#1}}
```

However, with verse in `verse` environment, it becomes virtually impossible since LaTeX thinks that a break is always favourable after the `\end{verse}`, the end of the environment. I have been googling, but could not find the way to prevent it from breaking *after* the environment.

With prose, it works like a charm:

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[papersize={11cm, 15cm}, textwidth=10cm, textheight=11.2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand{\dated}[1]{\nobreak\par\noindent\null\hfill\textit{#1}}

\begin{document}
\null\vspace{2.3cm}
\lipsum[1]
\dated{30.01.2018}
\end{document}
```

[image: Correct breaking]

However, with poetry, not so much:

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[papersize={11cm, 15cm}, textwidth=10cm, textheight=11.2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand{\dated}[1]{\nobreak\par\noindent\null\hfill\textit{#1}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{verse}
    THERE was a young lady of Niger \\
    Who smiled as she rode on a Tiger; \\   
    They came back from the ride    \\
    With the lady inside,   \\
    And the smile on the face of the Tiger.
\end{verse}
\dated{30.01.2018}
\end{document}
```

[image: Incorrect break]

I cannot use `\needspace` because all verse goes in between those `\begin{verse}` ... `\end{verse}`, and there are several hundred poems, so I cannot paste `\needspace` for each last line of verse.

Maybe it is possible to redefine verse somehow? Or any other trick to make `\nobreak` work after `\end{verse}`?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Actually, I doubt \nobreak has any effect on \par.  IIRC, \nobreak increases the penalties for line breaking.  \nopagebreak increases the penalties for breaking a paragraph between pages, but must be applied at the beginning of the paragraph.  There ARE no penalties for breaking pages between paragraphs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution puts the date INSIDE the verse environment and attaches it to the last line.  While one can use `\unskip` or `\vskip-\lastskip` to remove some of the space at the end of the verse environment, if you are already on the next page it won't do you any good.

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[papersize={11cm, 15cm}, textwidth=10cm, textheight=11.2cm, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand{\dateverse}[1]{\hfill\rlap{\hspace{\rightmargin}%
  \llap{\raisebox{-\baselineskip}{\textit{#1}}}}}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{verse}
    THERE was a young lady of Niger \\
    Who smiled as she rode on a Tiger; \\   
    They came back from the ride    \\
    With the lady inside,   \\
    And the smile on the face of the Tiger.
    \dateverse{30.01.2018}
\end{verse}
\end{document}
```

---

It occurred to me that `\raisebox` was turning the date into a descender, and LaTeX only aligns baselines at the bottom of the page, not descenders.  To move the baseline, one must include the previous line inside a box.

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[papersize={11cm, 15cm}, textwidth=10cm, textheight=11.2cm, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand{\dated}[1]{\ifvmode\else\newline\fi
  \null\hfill\rlap{\hspace{\rightmargin}\llap{\textit{#1}}}}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{verse}
    THERE was a young lady of Niger \\
    Who smiled as she rode on a Tiger; \\   
    They came back from the ride    \\
    With the lady inside,   \\
    \parbox[b]{\dimexpr \linewidth-\itemindent}%
    {And the smile on the face of the Tiger.
    \dated{30.01.2018}}
\end{verse}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! I guess one should put up with the text going outside the text area, as shown by your frames... I accept your answer, but it still remains an open question: can a page break be suppressed after the end of an environment?

Comment: Not when it ends with \endtrivlist.